# Integrating Google Calendar in a Django application running on app engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I have been trying to integrate Google calendar into a Django application running on App Engine. I have managed to get the google-python-client-api working on my computer and even managed to get a Django app to run on my computer. However, I am unable to get the app compatible with the Django app that is deployed on the appengine. I tried importing all the dependencies - httplib, gdata, gflags but when I run that project it still gives me 500 error. Is there a way to make these 3 things play nice with each other or should I look to deploy Django natively somewhere else?

Comment: What does the 500 error say (in the logs)?

Comment: hey! I'm sorry - I've just been trying so many different things in the past few days that I don't remember and can't find that project anymore. I am pretty close to getting it work with the django-social-auth app. If I try this again, I'll post it here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally solved my problem. :-
I went into oauth2client/client.py, and there's a conditional before the

```
CACHED_HTTP = httplib2.Http('.cache')
```

so I commented out the conditional so it uses the other case:

```
CACHED_HTTP = httplib2.Http()
```

automatically, and this one does not call makedirs.

Found on: - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-python/tIwjdy28MzQ